# awk script to return results recursively

Tags: for-loop, awk

I have a data set as below (t.txt):

```
827 819
830 826
828 752
752 694
828 728
821 701
724 708
826 842
719 713
764 783
812 820
829 696
697 849
840 803
752 774
```

I have second file as below (t1.txt):

```
752
728
856
693
713
792
812
706
737
751
745
```

I am trying to extract column 2 elements of the second file from the first data set using a for loop.

I have tried :

```
for i in `cat t1.txt`
do 
awk -F " " '$1=i {print $2}' t.txt > t0.txt
done
```

Desired output is :

```
694
820
774
```

Unfortunately I am getting a blank file.

I have tried to do it manually like : `awk -F " " '$1==752 {print $2}' t.txt > t0.txt`

Results obtained are

```
694
774
```

How can I do it for the entire t1 file in one go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way: using `join`

```
$ join -o 1.2 <(sort t.txt) <(sort t1.txt)
694
774
820
```

`join` requires the files to be lexically sorted on the comparison field (the default field one). The `-o` option instructs `join` to output the 2nd field from the 1st file.

With `awk`

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {key[$1]; next} $1 in key {print $2}' t1.txt t.txt
694
820
774
```

That remembers the keys in `t1.txt`, then loops over `t.txt` (when the accumulated record number `NR` is not equal to the file's record number `FNR`), if the first field occurred in `t1`, print the second field.